# FragmentTabHost and async loading data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have FragmentTabHost with 2 tabs.
Each fragment (tab) need to load data from internet and display it.

If I am loading data onCreate and populating it then switching to another tab and back i have empty views.

```
TextView emailView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactdetails_pro, container, false);

    emailView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contactdetails_info_email);

    return convertView;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String id = getArguments().getString("id");

    MyTask pdthread = new MyTask(this.getActivity(), id, new AsyncTaskCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Detail detail) {
            emailView.setText(detail.getEmail());
        }
    });
    pdthread.execute();
}
```

Comment: if you're not switching tabs the data is displayed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `FragmentTabHost` but you can try this (note: you may have to make the `Detail` class implement `Serializable`):

```
Detail mDetail = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String id = getArguments().getString("id");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        MyTask pdthread = new MyTask(this.getActivity(), id, new AsyncTaskCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Detail detail) {
                mDetail = detail;
                emailView.setText(mDetail.getEmail());
            }
        });
        pdthread.execute();
    } else {
        mDetail = (Detail)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("detail");
        if (mDetail ! = null) {
            emailView.setText(detail.getEmail());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("detail", mDetail);
}
```